# How can we decide the technology Asp.Net or Asp.Net MVC is suitable for my App

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am planning to create a web application(like shopping cart). Which is better technology Asp.net MVC or pure Asp.net? In other words which are the criteria that we consider while selecting a these technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://blog.gadodia.net/choosing-between-webforms-and-mvc/) is a good article for deciding which technology should be using, included comparing of strengths and weaknesses.

> **Asp.Net MVC SWOT**
>
> Strengths
>
> - Provides fine control over rendered HTML.
> - Cleaner generated HTML.
> - Superior separation between UI and code.
> - Easier to unit test.
> - Can support multiple view engines.
> - By default uses RESTful interfaces for URLs – so better SEO.
> - No ViewState (this may also be a weakness).
> - Typical size of page is small.
> - Easy integration with frameworks like JQuery.
>
> Weaknesses
>
> - Not event driven, so maybe difficult for people who know only Asp.Net Webforms to wrap their minds around it.
> - Third party control library support is not that strong.
> - No ViewState(this is also a strength).
>
> Opportunities
>
> - Allows for Test Driven Development (TDD) – it is built with TDD in mind, so its much easier to write unit test cases, mock objects,
>     and to intercept the program flow.
> - Allows for reuse of the same models to present different UIs and Interfaces.
>
> Threats
>
> - Bigger ramp-up and training time required for developers with no or little experience in web application development.
>
> **Asp.Net WebForms SWOT**
>
> Strengths
>
> - Provides very good RAD development capabilities.
> - Great designer support in Visual Studio.
> - Ease of development for data-heavy LOB applications.
> - Very rich control libraries and third party vendor support.
> - A familiar event-driven model when compared to Windows Forms development, and so easy for developers to pick up.
>
> Weaknesses
>
> - UI logic coupled with the code, and thus is hard to separate.
> - Harder to unit test, so difficult to employ TDD.
> - Heavy page sizes due to view state management.
>
> Opportunities
>
> - Great at creating quick prototypes for business applications. This comes in very handy when trying to show quick Proof of Concepts
>     to clients.
>
> Threats
>
> - Harder to adopt to various UI views despite the various frameworks available (master pages, Themes, etc.).

In my opinion, you should decide it yourself. As for me - I am deciding in the following way:

- if target application need to be intranet - **Web Forms**, if public - **MVC**
- if client side planned to be rather big - **MVC**, if it will be good to replace client side by server side processing - **Web Forms**
- if I want strong page architecture in my project - **Web Forms**, if I allowing custom pages and custom processing - **MVC**

These three items are only in my opinion.

In your case (shopping cart), I suggest to use **MVC**, because it is public (*first item*) and required rather big client side (*second item*)